# What is an adjective that means that something is shaped like a cube?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is an adjective that means that something is shaped like a cube? If something is shaped like a sphere, it's spherical. What would it be called if the object was shaped like a cube? I'm using this word in a poem. The word is describing a cubicle. So cubic wouldn't work. Sorry for being so picky!

Comment: It’s just *square*. A *square* building. Etc

Comment: Yeah, but square-ish is more what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then quadrilateral? Trapezoidal? Rectangular? Etc. You have to know the specific meaning you want to get a specific word. [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: "cubiform" ----

Comment: Alternatively *cuboid*.

Comment: As an adjective, *rectilinear*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuboid describes a square-shaped object with six rectangular sides.  No idea if that works with your poem, though.

If it was a cubicle that looks small from the outside but is larger within, it would be a tardis (think Dr. Who).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

If something is a square, then it is *square*!  You could use the word  *tetragonal*, derived from Greek *tetragonos (τετράγωνος) *If it is a cube, then it is *cubic*.

Comment: I'm using this word in a poem. The word is describing a cubicle. So cubic wouldn't work. Sorry for being so picky!

Comment: @JamesGreene Then why do you need to describe its shape?